Dual monitors with MacBook pro 2023 14 m3 chip
Any hack/work around to use dual monitors with mackbook pro 14 m3 (base/standard) chip ? 2023 model

Do you mean this? https://www.macrumors.com/2024/03/04/m3-macbook-pro-multi-display-support/

Super news. Hope it’s soon. Thanks @Mokubai

@Mokubai i wish you did not get our hopes up. Nothing on the horizon
